# Strategy.close not closing trade on bool condition?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

New to pinescript. I want to exit trade when close < lowest(low, 10) to act like a trailing stop. I cannot figure it out. the 1st entry works just fine. but the position never closes. thank you in advance.

```
stopChannelLong = ta.lowest(low, 10)
stopCalcLong = close < stopChannelLong[1] //and strategy.position_size > 0
//stopL = ta.valuewhen(stopCalcLong, bar_index, 0)
stopCalcShort = close < ta.highest(high[1], 10) and strategy.position_size < 0
//stopS = ta.valuewhen(stopCalcShort, bar_index, 0)
if strategy.position_size == 0      // new trade entry or re-entry 
    if strategy.closedtrades == 0   // first trade
        if (trade_direction==1 or trade_direction==0) and tb_rb_longSignal
            strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=close)
            strategy.close(id="Long", comment="Long Exit", when=stopCalcLong)
            pos_dir := 1
        if (trade_direction==-1 or trade_direction==0) and tb_rb_ShortSignal
            strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, stop=close)
            strategy.close(id="Short", comment="Short Exit", when=stopCalcShort)
            pos_dir := -1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your `strategy.close()` to be executed, the following conditions must be `true` **at the same time**.

1. `strategy.position_size == 0`
2. `strategy.closedtrades == 0`
3. `(trade_direction==1 or trade_direction==0)`
4. `tb_rb_longSignal`
5. `stopCalcLong`

Now, with `strategy.closedtrades == 0` you are checking that if there are any closed trades. In other words, if it is the very first trade. This condition will only be `true` for the first trade and for the later trades it will be `false` and your `strategy.close()` will not be executed. This explains the behavior you described in your question.